# How to do validate full name in JS in React Native

Tags: javascript, regex, react-native

I have a simple form for signup to my app in React Native. In one step, im validate the name of user is full. Initially, i writing a regex for validate characters and size min and max, but i need validate of a structure of name, with the before rules.

**Examples**
Valid names: *Luke Skywalker*, *Ben Skywalker*, *Lu Skywalker*
Invalid names: *L Skywalker*, *Luke*

**My regex start here:**

```
const rule = /^[a-zA-Z ]{2,40}$/;
```

How i would should write this regex? Grouping these rules?

Comment: Are there really only _three_ valid names?  Or, are the 3 names you gave just an example of the types of names which are valid?  If the latter, then can you also tell us the logic for discerning a correct name from an incorrect one?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen just examples. The rule consider two or more names, with 3 characters min and 40 maximum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try the following as a start: `^[a-zA-Z]{2,40} [a-zA-Z]{2,40}$`

```js
const pattern = /^[a-zA-Z]{2,40}( [a-zA-Z]{2,40})+$/;

console.info(pattern.test('Luke Skywalker'));
console.info(pattern.test('Ben Skywalker'));
console.info(pattern.test('Lu Skywalker'));

console.info(pattern.test('Lu Saber Skywalker'));
console.info(pattern.test('Ben The Ghost Skywalker'));

console.info(pattern.test('L Skywalker'));
console.info(pattern.test('Luke'));
```

Comment: Thank a lot Chev! In this pattern, you consider fixed two names, but, how can valid two or more names dynamically? Examples:  *Luke Skywalker Chev* or *Luke Skywalker Sky Walker*

Comment: Great! That's worked for me! Thank you for the help! :)